# Basement foundation wall repair

Tags: walls, foundation

After we poured some concrete outside of our east wall, we noticed some cracks along the foundation wall. I guess due to the weight of the new foundation, the foundation wall crumbled. One of the cracks made its way to a window well. The horizontal crack is about 4 ft above the concrete.

I talked to a couple of contractors. One of them recommended carbon fiber fabric, which looks like band aids, and another one recommended steel beam foundation reinforcement. I read some negatives about steel beam foundation reinforcement. Due to the cost of anchors or piering, I have to rule them out.

The house is located in Denver, CO. which has a dry climate. It can get extremely cold. I also had some issues with rain water making its way to my basement. I hired a company to install a french drain inside to address the water problem. I also want to address this wall issue before it is too late. [image]

I am leaning towards band aids, but I am not 100% sure. Does anybody have any experience with this application? If so, what was the end result? We have quotes from a couple of contractors.

Edit: This picture shows the outside on the other side of the foundation wall.
Notice the window well on the lower left, which is on the other side of this crack.[image]

Comment: How thick is the foundation wall, how tall is it overall and how far is the backfill dirt up against it (how high)? Do you have the new floor system bearing on it yet?

Comment: I forgot to ask, how much rebar is in it? Spacing and diameter of bars?

Comment: The foundation wall is probably 7-8 feet tall. I believe it is one ft thick. The I think the rebars where every 3ft or so on the outside. When they were pouring the new concrete, I saw that they weren't that thick at all. There was an existing slab there, which the concrete company removed before pouring the new concrete. There is dirt underneath the concrete.

Comment: If it is a foundation wall, it should have dirt on one side, creating pressure to crack the wall, that is the dirt I am referring to. The rebar does not have to be big, 1/2" or 5/8" will work if there is enough of it, depending how high the dirt is on the outside pushing against the wall. Is there an engineer or architect involved, there should be a spec on the rebar to follow.

Comment: @isherwood this photo shows the crack inside the basement. Concrete slab is on the other side of the wall on this picture. I will update the post as soon as I get a better picture.

Comment: @Jack Yes, there is dirt on the other side. The concrete slab sits probably 2 ft above the crack line. There wasn't an engineer or an architect involved when we poured the concrete slab outside.

Comment: The slab out side is straight forward stuff, the wall that has a crack in it is what i was referring to. As in who specified the amount of steel (reinforcing bar/rebar) that went into the wall. What I am getting at is the wall was not structured to hold back the pressure the wall was needing to hold back. Definitely not a good thing. Your contractor should be held responsible for an under engineered wall and be held liable for its repair. It is not up to you to fix his stuff, or for you to pay extra for something that was not done right to begin with.

Comment: One more question, how long was the concrete poured before it was backfilled? there is usually a minimum time to wait. Any time before that it will crack the wall... Then again, maybe the only reason it cracked is it did not have enough steel put in it. I am used to seeing at least a 1' by 1' grid. Beyond that, any of this is described by an engineer. Then they determine whether it needs to be #4, #5 or even #6 or larger rebar. Sometimes it needs to be a "double cage". I apologize for the jargon....

Comment: Are you positive that wall in concrete? I'm seeing very faint horizontal mortar lines (hard to make out). If so a block wall is more prone to fail than a poured wall. Before they poured the new slab did they happen to use a plate compactor on the fill sand?

Comment: How soon after you poured the concrete, did you notice the crack?   It's been quite some time since you posted this ... did you do anything to resolve it?

Comment: From your description it sounds light on the rebar. The last below grade wall / foundation I poured had rebar spaced 6" vertically and 1" horizontally, anything more than 3' below grade requires an engineering stamp. I think we had to wait 3 weeks prior to back fill and it was pea gravel to improve drainage with a drain at the bottom. Since this is an older post have things been repaired or fixed?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to consider a third repair on how to [repair block walls](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=X-tPXmfdAQM). It involves drilling an opening through the wall at a pre-determined angle and sinking a large all-thread rod with an expanding head (like a toggle bolt) into the soil. The expanded end anchors the rod making it rigid and un-moveable. The other end projects from the basement wall. It now has large heavy-duty washers installed followed by a hex nut. The nut is tightened until it forces the wall back to plum. The rods are spaced accordingly along the length of the damaged wall.

I can't attest to how well this option works (although it looks feasible), but it is another choice that may work for you.

Comment: @ojait, i don't have enough clearance for an anchor solution. If you look at  the second picture, you will notice that there is new concrete slab and a garage on the other side.